# Custom Login for MVC3 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authentication

I want to build a website that displays user-specific information (e.g. user sees her own records when she logs in). I don't want to use MVC3 Internet Application with default Membership provider as I would like to experience building my own authentication. I found some links on the web but feel that I need more sources to read from.
My project is MVC3, Entity Framework with code first. Thank you,

Answer (score 3):

#### Desciption

You can implement your own custom MemberShip Provider with your own logic.

#### More Information

- [ASP.NET MVC 2 Custom Membership Provider Tutorial](http://theintegrity.co.uk/2010/11/asp-net-mvc-2-custom-membership-provider-tutorial-part-1/)
- [Codeplex: Custom Membership Providers](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/CustomMembershipProviders.aspx)
- [Using a Custom Membership Provider in an MVC Application](http://developingmycloudapp.wordpress.com/2010/06/20/using-a-custom-membership-provider-in-an-mvc-application/)
- [MSDN: Implementing a Membership Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I recently did a similar thing - we have an application written in classic ASP and I wanted to authenticate with .NET using the existing database tables at the same time (for anyone who's interested I first logged the user into the classic ASP side then posted their details to the .NET logon form causing it to do its own login process).

Pretty much everything I found suggested just writing my own MemberShip Provider (as suggested by (dknaack) and IPrincipal object to allow me to add additional fields I wanted (it was easier than extending the profile data).

It was actually very easy in the end; I didn't bother implementing all of the MembershipProvider functions because I didn't need them. Here I just use Entity framework to check if the username/password are valid but clearly you could use whatever you wanted.

Here's a dump of my code to get you started:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Web.Security;
using My.Company.Project.Entities;

namespace My.Company.Project.Classes
{
    public class ClassicMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
    {
        public override void Initialize(string name, NameValueCollection config)
        {
            base.Initialize(name, config);
        }

        public override MembershipUser CreateUser(string username, string password, string email, string passwordQuestion, string passwordAnswer, bool isApproved, object providerUserKey, out MembershipCreateStatus status)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool ChangePasswordQuestionAndAnswer(string username, string password, string newPasswordQuestion, string newPasswordAnswer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override string GetPassword(string username, string answer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool ChangePassword(string username, string oldPassword, string newPassword)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override string ResetPassword(string username, string answer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void UpdateUser(MembershipUser user)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
        {
            using (var entities = new ProjectEntities())
            {
                return entities.Buprofile
                           .Where(p => p.profileid == username &&
                                       p.profilepassword == password)
                           .Count() == 1;
            }
        }

        public override bool UnlockUser(string userName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override MembershipUser GetUser(object providerUserKey, bool userIsOnline)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override MembershipUser GetUser(string username, bool userIsOnline)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override string GetUserNameByEmail(string email)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool DeleteUser(string username, bool deleteAllRelatedData)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override MembershipUserCollection GetAllUsers(int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalRecords)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override int GetNumberOfUsersOnline()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override MembershipUserCollection FindUsersByName(string usernameToMatch, int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalRecords)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override MembershipUserCollection FindUsersByEmail(string emailToMatch, int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalRecords)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool EnablePasswordRetrieval
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public override bool EnablePasswordReset
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public override bool RequiresQuestionAndAnswer
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public override string ApplicationName
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
            set { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public override int MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public override int PasswordAttemptWindow
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public override bool RequiresUniqueEmail
        {
            get { return true; }
        }

        public override MembershipPasswordFormat PasswordFormat
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public override int MinRequiredPasswordLength
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public override int MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public override string PasswordStrengthRegularExpression
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }
    }
}
```

You can hook it  up by adding/updating in your web.config:

```
<membership defaultProvider="ClassicMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="ClassicMembershipProvider" type="My.Company.Project.Classes.ClassicMembershipProvider" applicationName="MyApplication" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

I also created a custom IPrincipal (based on http://blog.codevelop.dk/post/2007/11/24/ASPNET-20-Forms-authentication-Keeping-it-customized-yet-simple.aspx) which allows you to store various bits of data about the user in a UserData property (as mentioned, it looked far easier this way than to extend the user profile).

You can access UserData of a user once logged in by casting User: ((MyPrincipal)User).UserData - I overode the User property in my page base class so I could just use User. in future though:

```
/// <summary>
/// Override User and return a MyPrincipal with its additional data
/// </summary>
public new MyPrincipal User
{
    get { return HttpContext.Current.User is MyPrincipal ? (MyPrincipal) HttpContext.Current.User : null; }
}
```

In the end this was pretty pain-free, and far less hassle than writing my own from scratch yet I still have all the control I need.